# Always open to Android Home Page?

Tags: home-screen

On Android devices, is there a way to always default to the "home page" of apps when you open the phone?

On the Android phone, the user can make multiple "app pages" that contain app shortcuts. There is a "home page" for these apps.

Comment: Well, Android by itself means rather little. It depends on which launcher you are employing

Comment: Sorry! I meant Galaxy S8 Standard Launcher. Android 8.0.0. Samsung Experience 9.0.

Comment: I know it sounds like a very "StackExchange-stereotype-answer"-ish, but could I recommend you to switch to a generic launcher?